# Sound detector is not working with Johnny-five

Tags: javascript, node.js, johnny-five

I have two sound sensors which both are Arduino compatible. One is AVR PIC F Arduino Sensitive Audio Sound Microphone Mic Sensor Detection Module, another is just a different brand comes with Arduino kit. I tried to use the following code with Johnny-five:

```
var five = require("johnny-five");
var board = new five.Board();

board.on("ready", function() {
var mic = new five.Sensor("A0");

 mic.on("data", function() {
 console.log(this.value);
 });
});
```

I connected Digital output to A1 and Analog output to A0, and I tried only connecting to A0 without digital too. However, the AO output which is the (this.value in the code) are appearing a bit fluctuating but mainly steady value that is not affected by sound input at all. 
I tried C code to test the sensor, it works. So the hardware is good but I am sure the connection is correct or I need any extra code for this? 
Anyone has a sound sensor working with Johnny-five, please advise.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Did any one use LM393 with Johnny-five?

Comment: On Youtube, there is someone using SparkFun Sound Detector Sensor to work with Arduino and Johnny-five, any one here has a hands on?

Comment: Please remove the `robotframework` tag. Thanks.